# Irrational Answer from Word Problem

Tags: word-problem

**Instruction:**

> Write an equation to model each scenario. Then use the equation to solve the problem.

**Question:**

> 'A population of insects doubles every month. If there are 100 insects to start with, how many will there be after 7 months?'

**Answer:**

\begin{align}
y &= 100(2)^7\\
y &= 200^7\\
y &= \text{Quadrillion insects (WHICH DOESN'T MAKE SENSE)}
\end{align}

That just hits me as odd to get $12,800,000,000,000,000$.

Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$100(2^7)$ would be a better way to write it. What you have is slightly ambiguous to a new or inexperienced student of mathematics.

Just remember that $xy^z\neq(xy)^z$. Apply the exponent first because of order of operations.

Comment: Oh oh. Okay gotcha!

Comment: @RepeaterCreeper Yes. It should be $12800$ instead.

Comment: Thanks man! I will keep that in mind every single time I do one of these problems again.

Comment: One last thing why is the formula were using different from the one I see on the internet? Our Formula: y = a . b^t. What I see on the internet is f(t) = a(1 + r)^t

Comment: What you write as $f(t)$ is the compound interest formula, which does apply here.  The $a$ is the initial amount ($a = 100$) and $r$ is the rate of return in decimal form.  In your setting, the rate of return is 100%, since each month the population increases by 100%.  Thus $r = 1$.  And so $f(t) = 100(1 + 1)^t = 100 * 2^7$.